# "UI Toolkit" doesn't appear in Hierarchy

Tags: unity-game-engine, hierarchy

My version of **UI Builder**: "Version 1.0.0-preview.18 - October 12, 2021".

How it should be:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0gKfK.png)

What I have:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRqgc.png)

I thought something has changed in new versions towards creating *UI Document*, but it hasn't.
I have watched couple of brand new tutorials on **UI Builder** and there also showed how people create *UI Document object* in hierarchy.

Comment: Are both those screenshots on Windows?

Comment: @AlexGeorg Screenshots made on different platforms but I guess it's not a big deal at the moment.

Comment: Yeah that's what I assumed - UI designs like those are skinned by the OS I believe.